# Where is the mongo db executable from Meteor on OSX?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, intellij-idea

I want to run the mongo4idea plugin for IntelliJ.

It asks for the mongo executable.

I just installed Meteor.

Where is the mongo file in OSX?

Or do I have to install Mongo DB seperately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's under

```
~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tools/.<meteor-version-hash>++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/
```

and is called `mongod`

Comment: Ahh, thats a really intuitive and easy to remember path. Thank you.

Comment: and it's not meant for you to find it easily... just do `mongo` to get the client. and btw, the data is not there, the data is under your .meteor folder in your project.

Comment: This was helpful because I want to run the same version of mongo as I my Meteor install, to mount a backup of our production app locally, and I don't need to download mongo again.